# Should I commit nested git submodules?

Tags: git, kohana, git-submodules

I have a kohana email module(`modules/email`) as a git submodule in my project and the email module has a git submodule itself(`vendors/swiftmailer`).
When I init the `swiftmailer` submodule from within the `modules/email` submodule it shows the the modules/email is modified.
I don't want to commit it because I didn't change it plus I committed it before and it broke my git index(which I spent too much time fixing).
**What should I do? Add it to .gitignore or is there something better?**
I have little experience with git submodules. So thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you edit your `submodule`, you should commit it with message like `"Update submodule: xxx"`.
So when you had edited `swiftmailer`, your `modules/email` should be committed after the `seiftmailer` committed.

```
cd modules/email/vendors/swiftmailer
// do sth
git add .
git commit -m "Some modifies of swiftmailer"

cd ../..
git add vendors/swiftmailer
git commit -m "Update submodule: swiftmailer"

cd ../..
git add modules/email
git commit -m "Update submodule: email"
```

This way is recommended in `submodule`. And note you **should not** ignore it.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the insight.